# jquery displaying table rows dynamically in dom belonging to one/more particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the basic html structure:

```
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="1">
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:large"> 
            <span class="muted"> This is the first object </span> 
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="2">
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:large"> 
            <span class="muted"> This is second object </span> 
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="3">
        <p style="font-size:large"> 
            <span class="muted"> this is the third object </span> 
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

and then I have check boxes, the functionality i want is, 
if checkbox **1** is checked, only the **tr** with class **1** be displayed.

if checkbox **2** and **3** are clicked, the **tr** with class **1** gets hidden and **2**, **3** show in the dom.

again if checkbox **2**,**3** are unchecked and **1** is checked tr with class **2**, **3** do not show and **1** is showed.

How can this be done in jQuery?

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com/

Comment: are you sure you don't want radios? So choices toggle

Comment: i want, i want, i want. What have you done? Or were you hoping someone would just do your work for you?

Comment: i am new to jquery and was trying out stuff with `filter` was not sure what would be the best method to go on, hence i put it *raw* over here, to know the best possible method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using radios, since explanation seems to indicate you want a choice of either **2&3** or **1** to show. Radios cancel each other whereas checkboxes don't.

If this is not behavior wanted you need to clarify your explanation

HTML:

```
<label>Show All<input type="radio" value="0" name="radio"></label>
<label>1<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio"></label>
 <label>2 &amp; 3<input type="radio" value="23" name="radio"></label>
```

JS

```
var rows = $('tr');

$(':radio').change(function() {
    var classNum = $(this).val();
    rows.hide();
    var toShow;
    if( classNum=='0'){
       toShow=rows;        
    }else{
        toShow = classNum=='1' ? rows.filter('.1') :  rows.not('.1');
    }
    toShow.show();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wGLfX/